# How to make your controller ActionResult work and consume your model field names and interface?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have this ActionResult called "CreateLogin and it have its model "LoginCreateModel object type is button. The problem now this action-result is not working, due to fact that UserId is null and have table from the database that calls it.On my web.config i am configuring the database source and connection-string. Here is my logic below both CreateLogin ActionResult and Login ActionResult(this happens when users already exist must login, this one does not grant users after my validation from the model).

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(Login login)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                bool success = WebSecurity.Login(login.username, login.password, false);
                var UserId = GetUserID_By_UserName(login.username); // this is empty when debugged
                var LoginType = GetRoleBy_UserID(Convert.ToString(UserId)); // this becomes empty when degugged

                if (success == true)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(LoginType)))
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Rights to User are not Provide Contact to Admin");
                        return View(login);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Session["Name"] = login.username;
                        Session["UserID"] = UserId;
                        Session["LoginType"] = LoginType;

                        if (Roles.IsUserInRole(login.username, "Admin"))
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("AdminDashboard", "Dashboard");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("UserDashboard", "Dashboard");
                        }

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Please enter valid Username and Password");// this hit to my CreateAction as a validation error, when i want to create new user.
                    return View(login);
                }



            }
            else
            {
               ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Please enter Username and Password");
                return View(login);
            }

        }


        [NonAction]
        public string GetRoleBy_UserID(string UserId)
        {
            return objIAccountData.GetRoleByUserID(UserId);
        }

        [NonAction]
        public string GetUserID_By_UserName(string Username)
        {
            return objIAccountData.GetUserName_By_UserID(Username);
        }
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateLogin(LoginCreateModel objSubmit) // this does not pass at all, still dont know why its not.
    {
            if(objSubmit.btnSubmit == "Create")
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Details saved successfully";
        }
        return View(objSubmit);
    }
namespace eNtsaPortalWebsiteProject.Models
{
    public class LoginCreateModel
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100,ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be least {2} characters long", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string password { get; set; }


        [Required]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string btnSubmit { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Is the code throwing any errors? What is happening in the `GetUserID_By_UserName` method?

Comment: It does not have data, nor when i do a sql query. Im stuck

Comment: How does your connection string look like? Do you have Sql Express?

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Mystring" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=Gcobanim-L\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=true;Database=eNtsaRegistrationDB"/>
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Do you have data in the database?

Comment: Only on the Users and UsersInRole table from the database

Comment: Have you registered your sql connection in the startup class? And please show us the code for the `GetUserName_By_UserID(Username);` method.

Comment: I created this on Repositiory folder/AccountData.cs   public string GetUserID_By_UserName(string UserName)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyString"].ToString()))
            {
                var para = new DynamicParameters();
                para.Add("@UserName", UserName);

                return con.Query<string>("Usp_UserIDbyUserName", para, null, true, 0, CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();
            }
        }

Comment: Is there anything being returned from the stored procedure? -> `Usp_UserIDbyUserName`

Comment: int is a data type return that procedure

Comment: Is it returning a int like a 1 or a 2..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206829/discussion-between-entsa2019-mkontwana-and-orvar).